# how to install logstash on windows 7

Tags: logstash

How to install logstash on Windows 7?

I install zip file which size is 90 mb and then version is logstash-1.5.0
and extract then file and move it to the bath `C:\Logstash`

When I run:

```
C:\Logstash\logstash-1.5.0\bin\logstash
```

I have the following message:

```
io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated
No command given

Usage: logstash  [command args]
Run a command with the --help flag to see the arguments.
For example: logstash agent --help

Available commands:
  agent - runs the logstash agent
  version - emits version info about this logstash
```

any help 
thank you

Comment: Usually you will want to specify a command (such as `--help` or `agent`). Some commands need config files. If you're not sure what to do, you might read the manual.

Comment: This article seems to be good but i struggled a lot while working on it. specially on my win 7 machine. seems to be good piece of resource  when working on Win serve 2008 R2 and windows 10 https://www.ulyaoth.net/resources/tutorial-install-logstash-and-kibana-on-a-windows-server.34/

Answer (score 23):

The most simple way to get started and verify that your logstash is working is to start it with the following command

```
logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }'
```

this means that logstash will echo what you type in the console back out to the console, for example:

```
C:\logstash\bin>logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }'
io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated Settings:
Default filter workers: 4 Logstash startup completed
I typed this
2015-12-11T09:22:22.349Z MY_PC I typed this
and then I typed this
2015-12-11T09:22:26.218Z MY_PC and then I typed this
```

The next thing to do is read an input from something else, for example your windows logs.  For this you can save a config file to your bin folder, it can be called anything, for instance 'logstash.config'.  Contents as below

```
# contents of logstash\bin\logstash.config

input {
  eventlog {
    type  => 'Win32-EventLog'
    logfile  => 'System'
  }
}
output {
  stdout {  }
}
```

If you then run

```
logstash -f logstash.config
```

Leave this running for a bit and you will see that your windows event log gets written out to the console.  (You could trigger some events by running iisreset in a different console.)

not sure why is says "io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated", probably because it is running in a windows console, but logstash is still working.

Comment: This is really helpful. 
Going by your example, next if I need to parse a websphere log file, what would be type => and logfile => be ? 
Also, if I need to extract only certain information from these logs and store it somewhere, what should be my configuration ?

Comment: In order for this to work on my Windows 10 machine, I had to switch the single quotes to double quotes. I.e.: logstash -e "input...

Answer (score 3):

Make a conf file and paste it in bin folder of logstash 
and type 
in cmd logstash/bin>logstash agent -f logstash.conf

Comment: could you give some more Information about the conf file?

Answer (score 1):

You have to run logstash manually by command in windows 7.   tc-log.conf is my conf file. lslog.log is my log file. Change directory to the bin folder of logstash and run following command .

*make sure that you have done changes in command as per yours.

```
logstash agent -f D:/cloud/logstash-1.4.2/tc-log.conf -l D:/cloud/logstash-1.4.2/logs/lslog.log –verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this method but using the test command I obtained:
Cannot find Java 1.5 or higher.

I have %LS_HOME%, %JAVA_HOME% and the PATH updated.

Debugging the logstash.bat (with echo) I found error is raised by:
%JRUBY_BIN% "%LS_HOME%\lib\bootstrap\environment.rb" "logstash\runner.rb" %*

%JRUBY_BIN% and "%LS_HOME% are rightly defined:
- "C:\ELK\logstash\vendor\jruby\bin\jruby"
- "C:\ELK\logstash"

Thanks.